# lograr que vs lograr con que

Tags: gramática, verbos, preposiciones

Is `lograr con que` correct? For example:

```
No logro que me hagan caso.
```

Can I also say?

```
No logro con que me hagan caso.
```

Or is the use of `con` with `lograr` wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb "lograr", as well as its synonym "conseguir", is transitive. They can be followed by a noun, an infinitive, or a "que"-clause.

- No logro / No consigo su aprobación.
- No logro / No consigo convencerlos.
- No logro / No consigo **que** me hagan caso.

The version with "con que" is not grammatical. For "con" to work, the verb needs to take a prepositional phrase (complemento de régimen), for example:

- No estoy de acuerdo **con que** seas mi jefe. (Also, "no estoy de acuerdo en que ...")
- Coincido **con que** esa es la mejor solución. (Also, "coincido en que ...")

Answer (score 1):

Lo más correcto;

- No logro que me hagan caso.
- No consigo que me hagan caso.
- No logro que me hagan caso **con** los deberes. (**con** el tema de hacer los deberes).
- No consigo que me hagan caso **con** la bicicleta. (**con** el tema de la bicicleta).

---

**"No logro con que me hagan caso".**

Hay algunas personas, en ciertos ámbitos, que lo dicen, y te entenderán, pero no es lo más correcto o elegante.

**No logro con que me hagan caso.** (No consigo que me hagan caso **con** el tema de que me hagan caso)

Comment: ¿Y "no logro con **qué** me hagan caso" es válido?

Comment: @tac No solo no es válido, sino que es aun peor.

Comment: @tac No, no es válido, es incorrecto.

Comment: Pero si intenté N cosas diferentes con el fin de que un grupo de personas me haga caso y después de todo siguen sin hacerme caso. Si tras eso me enojo y alguien me pregunta por qué estoy enojado y entonces respondo "Probe A, B, C, ... pero  siguen sin escucharme. Estoy frustrado porque no consigo ..." ¿Qué se supone que debo decir? ¿"... no consigo encontrar aquello por lo cual me podrían hacer caso"? mmmm muy retorcido

Comment: - No sé ya que hacer para que me hagan caso. - No sé ya que hacer para que me obedezcan. - No logro que me obedezcan - No sé con que entretenerles para que me hagan caso.- No sé con que cosa entretenerles para que me hagan caso.- No sé que hacer con mi futuro si no cumplen mis ordenes :).